# k-means: Same clusters for every execution

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis, k-means

Is it possible to get same kmeans clusters for every execution for a particular data set. Just like for a random value we can use a fixed seed. Is it possible to stop randomness for clustering?

Answer (score 19):

Yes.  Use `set.seed` to set a seed for the random value before doing the clustering.

Using the example in `kmeans`:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")


set.seed(2)
XX <- kmeans(x, 2)

set.seed(2)
YY <- kmeans(x, 2)
```

Test for equality:

```
identical(XX, YY)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: A note to explain why use `set.seed` each time. This is due to when calling a random number generation function, the output depends on the values of `.Random.seed`, that changes after executing these functions.  ref: https://r-coder.com/set-seed-r/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, calling `set.seed(foo)` immediately prior to running `kmeans(....)` will give the same random start and hence the same clustering each time. `foo` is a seed, like `42` or some other numeric value.

Comment: just add to Andrie and Gavin's response, I've tested that even when we set the `nstart` argument in the kmeans() bigger than 1, i.e. having multiple iteration of random seeding, the set.seed() will get producible identical results.